# How do I get details of which item in a RecyclerView was clicked to generate a context menu?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm using a FirebaseRecyclerView to show a list of 'Charts' (defined in the app) in a Fragment in my app. The items in the list can be long-clicked to pop up a menu with options.

The difficulty I have is that when the user clicks on an item in the pop up menu, I can't get the id of the item that was clicked.  I've included the relevant parts of ChartListFragment below, and marked where I'm having a problem.

```java
public abstract class ChartListFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chart, ChartViewHolder> mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecycler;

    public ChartListFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_charts_list, container, false);

        mRecycler = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.charts_list);
        mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayoutManager mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);

        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query chartsQuery = getQuery(mDatabase);
        mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chart, ChartViewHolder>(Chart.class, R.layout.item_chart,
                ChartViewHolder.class, chartsQuery) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final ChartViewHolder viewHolder, final Chart model, final int position) {
                final DatabaseReference chartRef = getRef(position);
                final String chartKey = chartRef.getKey();

                registerForContextMenu(viewHolder.itemView);

                viewHolder.bindToPost(model);
            }
        };

        mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        if (v.getId()==R.id.chart_item) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_long_press_chart_name, menu);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    // AT THIS POINT I THINK I SHOULD BE ABLE TO GET THE POSITION OF THE ITEM
    // THAT WAS CLICKED BY DOING SOMETHING LIKE
    //      int chartPos = info.position;
    //      Chart chartClicked = mAdapter.getItem(chartPos);
    // BUT info IS NULL, SO info.position CAUSES A CRASH
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.edit:
                // Show Edit Activity
                return true;
            case R.id.delete:
                // Show confirmation message
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution has a lot of moving parts, but overall the concept is pretty simple: use an `Intent` to pass the data you want. You can't rely on the `ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo` parameter, because this is only present when your context menu is attached to a `ListView` or `GridView`.

The first step is you need to get all information you will eventually want (this could be position or it could be something more direct) into your `ViewHolder`. You need this because you can call `RecyclerView.getChildViewHolder()` in `onCreateContextMenu` in order to access the data associated with whichever item you clicked on.

The next step is to attach this data to the context menu using an `Intent`. In your `onCreateContextMenu()` implementation, after  you inflate your menu, you can write something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    ...
    MyViewHolder holder = (MyViewHolder) recycler.getChildViewHolder(v);
    int position = holder.position; // or any custom data you want, set up in onBindViewHolder()

    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("position", holder.position);
    menu.findItem(R.id.your_item_here).setIntent(data);
    menu.findItem(R.id.your_other_item_here).setIntent(data);
}
```

Finally, in your `onContextItemSelected()` implementation, you can access this `Intent` and get your data out of it:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int position = item.getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);
    // do something with position
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I wanted to pass the ChartKey String through, so set that up as a variable in the ViewHolder, which was then populated in bindToPost. I got a bit confused by the lines menu.findItem(R.id.your_item_here), as I was putting the id of the actual list item, before realising it was meant to be the menu items, so I just put menu.findItem(0) and menu.findItem(1), which worked.Again, thank you so much, Ben, this really helped!

Comment: `MyViewHolder holder = (MyViewHolder) recycler.getChildViewHolder(v);` doesn't work for me because `v` is the `RecyclerView` itself and not a child view of it. Any hints on what might be happening?

Comment: @DanXPrado the OP was calling `registerForContextMenu()` for each `ViewHolder`'s item view; you must be calling it directly on your `RecyclerView`. That in and of itself isn't "bad", but it will mean that _conceptually_ the user is clicking on the recyclerview and not on an item, so you won't have an item to work with.

Comment: @BenP. that makes perfect sense. I don't like calling `registerForContextMenu()` for each view though. I decided to extend `RecyclerView` and override `showContextMenuForChild` and fill MenuInfo correctly. This way I can use the MenuInfo object received in `onCreateContextMenu`/`onContextItemSelected` without any additional code. Thank you!